# How to apply a function to a data.table subset by multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, apply

I have a data table with counts for changes for multiple groups. For example:

```
input <- data.table(from = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 to = c(letters[1:6], letters[1:6]),
                 from_N = c(100, 100, 100, 50, 50, 50, 60, 60 ,60, 80, 80, 80),
                 to_N = c(10, 20, 40, 5, 5, 15, 10, 5, 10, 20, 5, 10),
                 group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
```

How can I calculate the total for each change across groups? I can do this using a for loop, for example:

```
out <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(input$from))){ 
  sub <- input[from == unique(input$from)[i]] 
  out2 <- list()
  for (j in 1:length(unique(sub$to))){
    sub2 <- sub[to == unique(sub$to)[j]]
    out2[[j]] <- data.table(from = sub2$from[1],
                  to = sub2$to[1],
                  from_N = sum(sub2$from_N),
                  to_N = sum(sub2$to_N))
    print(unique(sub$to)[j])
  }
  out[[i]] <- do.call("rbind", out2)
  print(unique(input$from)[i])
}
output <- do.call("rbind", out)
```

However, the data table I need to apply this to is very large, and I therefore need to maximise performance. Is there a data.table method? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I've overlooked something, but it seems you're just after:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(input)[, .(from_N = sum(from_N), to_N = sum(to_N)), by = .(from, to)]
```

Output:

```
   from to from_N to_N
1:    A  a    160   20
2:    A  b    160   25
3:    A  c    160   50
4:    B  d    130   25
5:    B  e    130   10
6:    B  f    130   25
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
input %>%
 group_by(from, to) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(ends_with('_N')), sum)
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[, lapply(.SD, sum),  by = .(from, to), .SDcols = patterns('_N$')]
```